How do I display the Sum records of a child property in a field in the parent model?
How do I display the Sum records of a child property in a field in the parent model?
for example
Order Model:
  public class Order
  {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public long SumPrice { get; set; }

    public ICollection<OrderDetails> OrderDetails{ get; set; }
  }

OrderDetail Model:
public class InvoicesDetails
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public long Quantity { get; set; }
    public long Price { get; set; }
  
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Order Id))]
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}

How do I display the Sum records of Price property in a field SumPrice in the Order model?
I want to get the sum in this model and I don't want to calculate it while saving and write it to the parent model.

Personally I'd do it like [NotMapped]public long SumPrice => OrderDetails.Sum(od => od.Price) - is it what you mean? To have the parent have a property that will sum, any time it is asked, the present list of prices, but this sum is never stored or loaded from db...

Side note, you seem to have a class called OrderDetails which you said that second code block was but that class is called InvoicesDetails.. I'm sure it doesn't detract from the point in making but wanted to point it out that if you've edited the code for our benefit, it might have a typo. Also also, please don't give classes plural names. A class should be one thing; a person, an order.. we don't write class People or class Orders. If making a class that represents a collection of things, and for some reason just using a eg List is no good, call it PersonCollection, not People

To this end your Order class should have eg a ICollection<LineItem> LineItems, not a ICollection<LineItems> LineItems. The class name is singular: LineItem. The property that is a list of them is plural: LineItems

@flackoverstow That's exactly what I mean. [NotMapped]public long SumPrice => OrderDetails.Sum(od => od.Price); But it gives an error. System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source'

Ah, perhaps consider OrderDetails?.Sum(od => od.Price) ?? 0 - you don't initialise your collection to anything so it will be null if you didn't download any order items from the database. You could also consider setting the order details property to a new list/hashset/whatever so that it isn't null if nothing has been downloaded

@flackoverstow OrderDetails?.Sum(od => od.Price) ?? 0 Returns 0

Have you considered debugging to find out why? Possibly OrderDetails is null like your previous error suggest or OrderDetails is empty or all Items prices in OrderDetails are 0 or there are positive and negative prices in there that sum up to 0. There are many possibilities why and you should find out via debugging.

See docs: PostsCount property implementation.

As mentioned you can use an unmapped helper:
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public long SumPrice { get; set; }
    
    [NotMapped]
    public int OrderDetailCount => OrderDetails.Count;

    public ICollection<OrderDetails> OrderDetails{ get; } = [];
}

*note: Always initialize collection navigation properties and protect the setter. Code consuming an entity should never be able to "set" a collection navigation property. Initializing it ensures you don't end up with a NullReferenceException, the collection is initialized and ready to go.
However, there is a limitation here in that the count will only be accurate when you eager load the OrderDetails collection. By default on a new DbContext instance if you fetch just the Order you would get a count of 0. Worst case you can get an inaccurate count if the DbContext happens to have loaded (tracking) a subset of order details that happen to be associated to this order. Tracked entities will automatically be linked to collections etc. when a related entity is loaded. You also cannot use an unmapped helper in Linq query expressions that would get translated to SQL. For instance you cannot use something like: var smallOrders = _context.Orders.Where(o => o.OrderDetailCount < 5);
Eager loading all OrderDetails to get a count can be an expensive operation, especially if you want to search and display a list of Orders.
A better solution when it comes to reading data and having access to summary details like this is to use projection when reading. For instance if we want to list a set of Orders and include their order details count:
public class OrderSummaryViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public long SumPrice { get; set; }
    public int OrderDetailCount { get; set; }
}

Then when reading our search results:

var orders = await _context.Orders
    .Where(o => o.Date >= startDate && o.Date < endDate)
    .Select(o => new OrderSummaryViewModel 
    {
        Id = o.Id,
        Title = o.Title,
        Date = o.Date,
        SumPrice = o.SumPrice,
        OrderDetailCount = o.OrderDetails.Count
    }).ToListAsync();

This can be simplified by using a mapper like Automapper or Mapperly, etc. which can leverage EF's IQueryable to build a query expression and populate the view model as a one-liner.
Often the view models will only need a subset of data from the actual model graph. This allows EF to build more efficient queries and there is no worry about missing an eager load or the cost overhead of Cartesian Products building queries to get back everything.
